# CSS working differently when the site is access via www and directly via @

Tags: css, fonts

I am very confused by an issue I am seeing on my production site.

When I access the site via "www", everything looks like expected and matches my local development environment.  The css is spot-on.

But if I access the same site with just the domain name the fonts kind of become larger and the site becomes ugly.  Has anyone experienced a similar problem?

Maybe I am missing something as 100 things are flying around for me right now.

The urls in question:

```
http://www.connect4fitness.com
http://connect4fitness.com
```

And, yes the DNS entries are correct.  Both urls should be serving the same pages!

Comment: I see no difference. I would make sure your cache is completely cleared out. If you are still having the issue, browser and OS might help.

Comment: What do you mean by "directly via @"?

Comment: by @ I mean without the "www" domain prefix, i.e. http://connect4fitness.com (instead of http://www.connect4fitness.com)

Comment: @Ktash - are you not seeing the fonts etc. bigger on the second URL?  I will try clearing local cache again but this is happening for all pages.. even new ones.

Comment: @Tabrez No, I am seeing no difference between the two pages. You might want to look at Ben D's answer, as that may also be the issue.

Comment: @Ktash - if the stylesheets are cached, it will carry over to new pages (this is more or less the point of caching), but I'm still betting on the zoom-level of your browser being the issue.

Comment: @Ktash - clearing the cache again did not help.  The difference is small maybe 3-4% difference.  But look at the "Sign up now" link on the right.  In the www-based url it is on one line.  In the other it wraps down to second line.  I will check out Ben's answer now.

Comment: @Tabrez They are literally pixel for pixel the same. I see no difference. And @BenD, that's true, but if he recently changed url for the stylesheets, or if he has them setup to follow `www.connect4fitness.com/cssfile` vs `connect4fitness.com/cssfile`, they will be cached differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you're just viewing at the wrong zoom level. What browser are you using? In the version where the fonts are large, make sure you're veiwing at 100% zoom level (generally this is done by hitting Ctrl+0 (that's a zero) or zoom in and out with Ctrl+(either plus or minus +/-). Most modern browsers remember your last zoom level for a specific site, and do differentiate between sub-domains, so you you zoomed in at some point it will remember it only on the http://connect4fitness.com.

Comment: Ben - you are the man!!  That was the issue!  Clearing the cache was not fixing it but a reset zoom did the trick.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `@font-face` rules in your CSS, the path(s) to the fonts have to match the domain from which they're requested — this is referred so as the *same origin policy*.

For example, if you're viewing this page:

```
http://example.com/about
```

and the fonts are being served via CSS from:

```
http://www.example.com/css/screen.css
```

You'll encounter the same origin policy and the browser will not download the font files (since the fonts specified in the CSS are being served from a different domain. Remember, sub-domains such as `www` are technically considered a separate domain).

To easiest way to fix the problem is to link to your fonts in your CSS using relative (`../`) or absolute paths (`/`), and avoid using your site's FQDN if at all possible..

**Good** (Relative):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyWebFont';
    src: url('../fonts/webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}
```

**Best** (Absolute):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyWebFont';
    src: url('/fonts/webfont.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/fonts/webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/fonts/webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/fonts/webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}
```

**Bad** (FQDN):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyWebFont';
    src: url('http://example.com/fonts/webfont.eot');
    src: url('http://example.com/fonts/webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('http://example.com/fonts/webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://example.com/fonts/webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('http://example.com/fonts/webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}
```

Comment: rjb..thanks for the reply.  But the issue turned out to be what Ben mentioned in his answer.